# restricting a pgfplots-based curve on a specified axis

Tags: pgfplots

I'm new to pgfplots and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to restrict a curve to a certain x-axis range. I've created a pgfplots based figure shown below

[image: first draft picture]

It is based on the following `tex` file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}              
\usepackage{pgfplots}


% useful commands and definitions
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2 *sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}     
        \begin{axis}[
            height=5cm, width=12cm,
            no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100,
            axis lines*=left,
            ylabel=$y$,
            ymax=0.45,
            hide y axis,
            every axis x label/.style={
               at=(current axis.right of origin),
               anchor=west
            },
            xlabel=$x$,
            xtick={3,6.5},
            xticklabels={$\mu_0$, $\mu_1$},
            ytick=\empty,
            enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
            grid = major
        ]
        \addplot[very thick, cyan!50!black]{gauss(6.5,1)};

        \node[above, red!50!black] at (axis cs:3,0.45) {Reference Value};
        \node[above, red!50!black] at (axis cs:6.5,0.45) {Sensor Value};

        \draw[thick,arrows={<->}] (axis cs:3,0.3) -- (axis cs:6.5,0.3)
              node[pos=0.5,above] {Accuracy};

        \draw[thick,arrows={<->}] (axis cs:4.9,0.1) -- (axis cs:8.1,0.1)
              node[pos=0.5,below] {Precision};

        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The picture contains a x-axis range from `(0,10)`, and has a blue normal density (gaussian) curve with a mean at tick point `\mu_1 = 6.5`. I would like to restrict gaussian curve from `\mu_0 = 3` to 10, instead of having it rendered from `(0,10)`.

I tried changing the statement making the gaussian curve from:

```
\addplot[very thick, cyan!50!black]{gauss(6.5,1)};
```

to:

```
\addplot[very thick, cyan!50!black, domain=3:10]{gauss(6.5,1)};
```

to achieve this effect, but now the figure looks like this:

[image: code adjustment]

The range of the x-axis is from (3,10), not (0,10).  How do I make the picture look like:

[image: desired picture]

*I removed the blue line from `(0,3)`, or `(0,\mu_0)`, by hand using gimp here.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `domain=3:10` in `\addplot` options and put `xmin=0,xmax=10` in axis options.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% useful commands and definitions
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2 *sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            height=5cm, width=12cm,
            no markers,  samples=100,
            xmin=0,xmax=10,  %% <-------------------------
            axis lines*=left,
            ylabel=$y$,
            ymax=0.45,
            hide y axis,
            every axis x label/.style={
               at=(current axis.right of origin),
               anchor=west
            },
            xlabel=$x$,
            xtick={3,6.5},
            xticklabels={$\mu_0$, $\mu_1$},
            ytick=\empty,
            enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
            grid = major
        ]
        \addplot[very thick, cyan!50!black,domain=3:10]{gauss(6.5,1)};

        \node[above, red!50!black] at (axis cs:3,0.45) {Reference Value};
        \node[above, red!50!black] at (axis cs:6.5,0.45) {Sensor Value};

        \draw[thick,arrows={<->}] (axis cs:3,0.3) -- (axis cs:6.5,0.3)
              node[pos=0.5,above] {Accuracy};

        \draw[thick,arrows={<->}] (axis cs:4.9,0.1) -- (axis cs:8.1,0.1)
              node[pos=0.5,below] {Precision};

        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `axis cs:` is not needed anymore since certain version (I say “certain” because I'm not *certain*).

Comment: @Manuel From version 1.11 onwards it is not needed. But the OP has `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}` in his code meaning he may have that version where it is needed. So I left it :-)

Comment: Yes, the TeX installation that is available to me is a bit out of date, but it is good to know that 'axis cs' isn't needed in future versions.

Comment: @HarishKumar : Thanks!  This solution works great for me.

Comment: @indraniel Glad it helped. Have a nice time TeXing :-)